# Android bluetooth consecutive connection attempts fail

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

This is not so much a question about coding, but rather more about what exactly I'm doing wrong. I have an arduino with bluetooth that is configured to turn an led on/off when it receives 'L' or 'l'. 
Now with the app that im currently developing i can connect successfully to it and control the LED BUT if i exit the app and then re-open it it doesn't manage to establish connection and the app just freezes.. The only way i can manage to reconnect is if i press the reset button on the arduino. Any thoughts? Im leaning towards improper socket & datastream closure but I'm doing it by the book so... :/

P.S I don't think its the arduino sketch because with 'ArduinoRC' app that i downloaded from the play store I can connect and reconnect to it as many times as I want without pressing the reset button on the arduino..

Comment: and what happens when you turn off/on the bluetooth on your android phone?

Comment: No change what so ever, the only way I can get it to communicate again is if i press the arduino reset button. I looked into the bluetooth on/off thing as im using a nexus 4 and some searching showed me that some nexus 4 devices have had this similar problem and overcame it by turning BT on/off but that doesnt seem to be the case here.. :/

Comment: Threaded the methods which connect to the socket and open read/write streams and this has seemed to fix it.. Still don't understand what the problems was.. :/